# Problems with dynamic linq and nullable date is nulla

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dynamic

I've a problem with this dynamic linq query condition :

```
string query = "Filed = 0 AND DeletedDate IS NOT NULL";
var q = (from u in ctx.Table.Where(query).OrderBy(s => s.InitDate) select u)
```

I receive this exception :

> Operator 'and' incompatible with operand types 'Boolean' and 'DateTime?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting that error because Dynamic LINQ doesn't support the `IS NOT` operator.
You can find more information on what is supported by the library by downloading the files and documentation from [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx).

Instead, what you can pass it is:

```
Filed = 0 AND DeletedDate != null
```

Or even:

```
Filed = 0 AND DeletedDate <> null
```

Here's a table of the operators that it *does* support (taken from the documentation linked to above).

[image: Dynamic LINQ operators]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(Filed = '0') AND (DeletedDate IS NOT NULL)
```